# frequent lost of connection to mySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I instal wamp server locally on my PC.I create a user registration form using php and mySQL database for pratice.I was able to connect to my mySQl data server and if i input data on the form and submit is work successfully.I normal experience at time when i  access the user registration form it lost connection to my SQLdata server even though my wamp server is on.I will troubleshoot by changing some of the parameter by using mysqli_connect() to check if i will be prompted unsuccessful connection still nothing will show.When i check some other time it will work successfully.Please what may be causing this issue?

Comment: May firewall block running mysql server. Turn of firewall and try again

Comment: I have done it, it still didnt work

Comment: What errors are getting?

Comment: Am not getting any errors. if thought i use mysqli_connect(); to check for an error message, still not show

Comment: Are you using latest version?

Comment: Latest version of wampserver or text editor?

Comment: Please provide your connectivity code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Run wampserver as administrator by right clicking wampserver.exe file. It may help.
**Edit:**
With the type of english you are using to produce the problem and giving no code is making it difficult to predict what the problem actually is. But I think there is something wrong with your mysqli connection file. 
Add this code bit to the top of your registration.php file like this:

```
        <?php
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
        if(!$connection) {
            die("Failed to connect" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        else {
            echo "Connection Established";
        }

        $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'db2');
        if(!$select_db) {
            die("Database selection failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        else {
            echo "Database selected";
        }
        ?>

        <?php
       ////rest of ur registration code goes here
```

Comment: I already had an icon on my desktop.I ran it an administrator by right click on the short-cut icon of the wampserver.It didnt not connect

Comment: Have you ever succeeded connecting even once??

Comment: And it would be helpful if u provide the code for registration form and the connection establishment code as well.

Comment: Yes, I have connected before. I still have my data i inputed through my user registration form in my sql server. I have tried creating another user registration form (using Html & neccessary PHP code). I created another table in the database on myphpadmin. What baffles me is that i cant even connect to the sql server with the normal mysqli_connect(); if i run the function it will displace any message .